# Logback-rolling multiple services

Tags: java, logging, spring-logback

I'm trying to write logs of multiple services to same file, but my rolling policy given is not working, tried with both time based and size based rollings. Thing is my services are running simultanously and writting there logs to same file in my local directory. When tried to write logs by single service it is working as expected. 
Please help me to solve this issue tried with different rolling policies.

Appender to log to file​
    
        ${LOG_FILE}
        
            Minimum logging level to be presented in the console logs
            INFO
        
        
            ${LOG_PATH}/archived/log_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}_%i.log
             10KB

Answer (score 0):

I had an experience similar to yours with Log4j 1.x then I debugged an appender back then (~5-6 years ago) and came to the following conclusions:

I don't think you can write data from multiple services into the same file. In other words,
Logging framework usually assumes that only it can change the file. In some Operating Systems (windows) it will even stop writing into file if some other process will rename / change the current file.

Of course its just a code and you could create a more sophisticated appeneder that will probable make it work, but frankly I don't think it worth the effort.

So I suggest writing into different files, where file name can be generated in a way that it will contain a pid of the resource. The downside of this method is that if the process dies and then re-runs, on-one will take care of the old resources.

Another approach (somewhat similar) - is to create a folder with logs for each service so that they'll get different logs based on folder (even if files in these folders will be with the same name).

Comment: ya we can write the logs of each service in separate files and the rolling policy is working fine in this scenario. I tried with it already. Thanks for your time!!!...